# How to connect navigation links to jquery.mobile swiping pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery-mobile

I'm trying to create a webpage primarily for mobile. User navigates from page to another by swiping left or right. I have done this with jQuery mobile.

Now I would like to connect it to fixed navigation bar at the bottom of the screen, so that when user swipes the activated manu item changes accordingly. Can somebody give me a code for that?

Also I would like to make it so that when user clicks on a menu item, page changes with the same slide animation as when swiping. Now I have the animation on second menu item in a way that when it's clicked, the animation occurs but the sliding page is always the next one and not the exact page I want. So if user is on front page and then clicks on third menu item, it shows an animation of second page sliding to view and then jumps to third page, when it should automatically show animation of third page when you click third menu item.

Here is the swipe page script

```
function navnext( next ) {
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", next, {
        transition: "slide"
    });
}
function navprev( prev ) {
    $( ":mobile-pagecontainer" ).pagecontainer( "change", prev, {
        transition: "slide",
        reverse: true
    });
}


$( document ).one( "pagecreate", "#page1", function() {
    $( document ).on( "swipeleft", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
        var next = $( this ).jqmData( "next" );
        if ( next ) {
            navnext( next );
        }
    });
    $( document ).on( "swiperight", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
        var prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );
        if (prev) {
            navprev( prev );
        }
    });

    $( document ).on( "click", ".next", function() {
        var next = $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "next" );

        // Check if there is a next page
        if ( next ) {
            navnext( next );
        }
    });

    $( document ).on( "swiperight", ".ui-page", function( event ) {
        var prev = $( this ).jqmData( "prev" );

        if ( prev && ( event.target === $( this )[ 0 ] ) ) {
            navprev( prev );
        }
    });

    $( document ).on( "click", ".prev", function() {
        var prev = $( ".ui-page-active" ).jqmData( "prev" );

        if ( prev ) {
            navprev( prev );
        }
    });


});
```

And this is my structure where I have added the bad animation to menu item News

```
<div id="page1" data-role="page" data-prev="#page3" data-next="#page2">
    <div data-role="content" class="sivu">
      I am page 1
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page2" data-role="page" data-prev="#page1" data-next="#page3">
    <div data-role="content" class="sivu">
       I am page 2
    </div>
</div>
<div id="page3" data-role="page" data-prev="#page2" data-next="#page1">
    <div data-role="content" class="sivu">
        I am page 3
    </div>
</div>
<div class="scrollmenu" id="navbar" data-role="footer">
  <a href="#page1">Home</a>
  <a href="#page2" class="next">News</a>
  <a href="#page3">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
  <a href="#home">Home</a>
  <a href="#news">News</a>
  <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
  <a href="#about">About</a>
</div>
```

And here is link to code pen (it's not working for some reason)
https://codepen.io/pinjakumpulainen/pen/YMbNRx